# Which algorithm used by the rnorm function

Tags: r, random

Which algorithm is using by the `rnorm` function by default to generate standard-normally distributed random numbers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See `?RNGkind`. The default is an inversion algorithm:

> `normal.kind` can be "Kinderman-Ramage", "Buggy Kinderman-Ramage" (not
>   for `set.seed`), "Ahrens-Dieter", "Box-Muller", "Inversion" (the
>   default), or "user-supplied". (For inversion, see the reference in
>   `qnorm`.) The Kinderman-Ramage generator used in versions prior to 1.7.1
>   (now called "Buggy") had several approximation errors and should only
>   be used for reproduction of old results. The "Box-Muller" generator is
>   stateful as pairs of normals are generated and returned sequentially.
>   The state is reset whenever it is selected (even if it is the current
>   normal generator) and when kind is changed.

You can change the algorithm by

```
RNGkind(normal.kind = "Box-Muller")
```

You can find what is currently set by looking at `RNGkind()[2]`.

Comment: thank you, do you know, if the rnorm function is used by the mvtnorm package for generating standard normal distributed random numbers?

Comment: @Klaus yes, `mvtnorm`'s `rmvnorm` uses the same `rnorm` function.

Comment: they use the default option?

Comment: By quick look it seems that they do not define the generator in the codes, so `rmvnorm` uses whatever generator is set by `RNGkind`.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer is sufficient, but left me with some more questions; in particular, I didn't see anywhere in the documentation* what on earth the `"Inversion"` algorithm is, so I dived into the [source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/776708efe6003e36f02587ad47b2eaaaa19e2f69/src/nmath/snorm.c), which also gives academic references to the papers originating the other possible algorithms, to figure out what exactly is being done.

```
    case INVERSION:
#define BIG 134217728 /* 2^27 */
    /* unif_rand() alone is not of high enough precision */
    u1 = unif_rand();
    u1 = (int)(BIG*u1) + unif_rand();
    return qnorm5(u1/BIG, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
```

So it seems at base the default `"Inversion"` algorithm generates a high precision floating point number (looks like 53 bits, or the [mantissa size for 64-bit floating numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)), then sends it to the `qnorm5` function which is a CDF function for the normal distribution.

As to how the `qnorm5` function works (given there is no closed form for the Normal CDF nor inverse CDF), I haven't had much luck cracking what seems to be the source code [here](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/qnorm.c), but they do give further academic references, namely [Beasley, J. D. and S. G. Springer (1977)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346889) and [Wichura, M.J. (1988)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2347330); the former being typically used for small quantiles of the CDF and the latter for large (`z>7` or so).

It may also be interesting to note that (as of this writing) this algorithm appears to be [shared by the Julia language](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Rmath-julia/blob/master/src/qnorm.c), which also shares the `qnorm5` code used by `R`.

*To be fair, in retrospect, Wichura is mentioned in `?qnorm` which is referenced above. Still it's worthwhile to spell things out in this thread, I think.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this answer!