# Why do R commands rnorm() and qnorm(runif()) generate different random numbers?

Tags: r, random

I set the seed, generate uniformly distributed random numbers, and use the inverse CDF method to get a set of normally distributed random numbers. Then, I reset the seed and generate normally distributed random numbers using `rnorm()`. The results are different. Does not the random number generator in R default to the Mersenne-Twister algorithm to generate integers? Should not all the other random numbers in R (normal, uniform, exponential, etc. distributions) be some deterministic transformation of these pseudo-random integers?

```
set.seed(1)
u1 <- runif(5)
u1
# [1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
z1 <- qnorm(u1)
z1
# [1] -0.6264538 -0.3262334  0.1836433  1.3297993 -0.8356286
set.seed(1)
z2 <- rnorm(5)
z2
# [1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078
```

And yes, I see that some elements match, but do not necessarily appear in the same order. Can someone please explain?

Comment: I think the two vectors share 3 elements, and you are right - only looking at the elements that are the same the order is preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like the elements all appear and in the same order, but there is always an extra element interspersed in the output of your first method.

That seems to suggest that `rnorm` consumes two random numbers for each iteration, and that is in line with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32278484/14955).

```
case INVERSION:
#define BIG 134217728 /* 2^27 */
/* unif_rand() alone is not of high enough precision */
u1 = unif_rand();
u1 = (int)(BIG*u1) + unif_rand();
return qnorm5(u1/BIG, 0.0, 1.0, 1, 0);
```

Looks like it takes the second number for the less significant bits.

That would mean that the "same" numbers you observed also become slightly different when you look at more digits.

Comment: I will concede this explains the behavior of the rnorm function, although the C function qnorm5 returns only one double, so it is not clear to me where the second number comes from. I have tried the same trick with rexp() and cannot detect a pattern. Any thoughts?

`> set.seed(1)
> u1 <- runif(5)
> u1
[1] 0.2655087 0.3721239 0.5728534 0.9082078 0.2016819
> z1 <- qexp(u1)
> z1
[1] 0.3085771 0.4654124 0.8506279 2.3882278 0.2252482
> set.seed(1)
> z2 <- rexp(5)
> z2
[1] 0.7551818 1.1816428 0.1457067 0.1397953 0.4360686`

Comment: Pascal, are you asking how to alight the rnorm() and the inverse CDF methods? Maybe just generate a vector twice as long when using the inverse CDF method and keep only the odd elements?

Comment: `rexp` is computed using loops, and takes up *a lot* of random numbers for each output: https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/sexp.c

Comment: "qnorm5 returns only one double". Exactly. That's how the extra number disappears. You feed in two random numbers, and you get back only one.

Comment: Oh, I see - unif_rand() is called twice in that block of code. I am convinced. If you do not mind answering, what is gained by using the loop for `rexp` instead of applying the quantile function to a uniform number?

Comment: Sorry, completely out of my depth here. But that could be a follow-up question (maybe more an statistics.stackexchange.com), and note that some paper is referenced in the source code, presumably it goes into the rationale.